# Where to connect shielded cable when you have no chassis?

Tags: grounding, emc, battery-operated, shielding, certification

I joined a project after some of the initial design decisions were made, so it’s not quite how I’d like it, which now presents me with a bit of a problem.

I have two power cables that are emitting noise. I’m going to work on a few solutions to get rid of the noise at source, but time restraints may mean I have to get a temporary solution in place first. One option is to change the cable to a shielded one, but I don’t have a chassis (at either end) to ‘ground’ to (enclosures at both ends are plastic).

One end is a battery box, the other a motor controller. I presume that as I can’t do 360° shielding, my next best bet is to connect the shield to the battery negative rail at only the battery box end.

Does anyone have any better solutions or am I going in the right direction?

Comment: What is the frequency (range) of the noise that you see?

Comment: It’s the switching noise of the IGBTs by the look of things, so around 16KHz (plus harmonics depending on power output, they go up into the 500KHz zone).

Comment: I doubt the shield connection at the battery box end will make much difference, but the (-) terminal is as good as anything would be. On the motor controller end, shield should be soldered to the PCB's clean ground plane.

Comment: You're  dealing with a problem generated by someone else - a patch-up job. Better to find the noise source and fix it there - likely at the motor-controller.

Comment: @Sylvester, Are you sure the noise is radiated? If the noise is conducted (and not radiated), the cable shield will have no effect.

Comment: @Kuba I’ll give that a go at one / other / both ends when I get the chance and will report back.

Comment: @vincent. We are trying to get it certified and are seeing it in radiated emissions. But it is there if we look at the conducted side (not needed for certification) and I’m assuming radiating from that.

Comment: @Glen. Yep, not my controller, battery system, or cable!  My main efforts are going to be in the controller and modifying their unit. Looking at adding small caps to the gate drive of the low side IGBTs and looking at the symmetry of the rising and falling edges.  The shielding is a backup plan (or to get us the last mile if the other stuff doesn’t quite lower the noise enough). The other alternative is a power line filter but that is $$$’s

Comment: @Sylvester, Your comment leads me to believe that you are testing the EN61000-4-3 standard. Is this the case?

Comment: You need to put a proper input filter on the power lines to the motor controller.  Maybe this can be done with a "dirty box" attached to the motor controller itself.

Comment: Note that in many weight sensitive applications like satellites, power cables are not shielded in order to save weight.  The plus and minus wires are twisted.

Comment: @vincent, not quite. EN60945

Comment: @SteveSh, that is indeed one of my options. But we are pulling a lot of amps (400 or so) and off the shelf power line filters are $400USD and up. We will do it if we have to, but that’s a lot of moola to add onto the product.

Comment: Also, Stevesh, yes, twisted and shielded would be good, but our cables are 17mm diameter so tricky to twist!  And getting them through a ferrite a few times adds a lot of footage!

Answer (score 0):

The noise current in the cable needs to be returned back to the source. If you are only dealing with 30MHz plus, you may just be able to capacitively couple The shield back to the source voltage rail or ground.

Ideally you would probably want two couple this to PCB ground. You need a low impedance pathway back to ground so keep the inductance low by keeping the shield near the PCB.

You could also try and do some experiments with the near field probe and see if you can come back on some of the radiation by grounding it to different points.

Comment: All our problems are actually below 30MHz.  Particularly in the 150KHz to 600KHz range.

Comment: Capacitive coupling should be enough, however, you will need to limit inductance

Comment: Yes, I did find some noise was better if I added caps over the power lines at the motor controller, but some worse. Once I get some shielded cables made up, I’ll add it to the list of options.